# Creating a DMG file on Gentoo

Tags: osx, gentoo, disk-image

I'm trying to create a Mac OS DMG image file on Gentoo - I managed to create the FS using mkfs.hfsplus and just dropping all the contents into the mounted file system, and everything works fine.. the problem is that I'm now trying to add an icon to the DMG, and from my understanding I have to compress it and make it read only (the dmg) as a final seal to make it work with the icon.

I've found a way to do this in OS X in the shape of:
`hdiutil convert $IMAGENAME-temp.dmg -format UDZO \
    -imagekey zlib-level=9 -o $IMAGENAME.dmg`
but finding it difficult to do on Gentoo, as hdiutil only exists on Mac OS.

Any way to achieve this without SSHing to a Mac OS machine?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do this with this open source software: [libdmg-hfsplus](https://github.com/hamstergene/libdmg-hfsplus) Or, use mkfs.hfsplus: [Gentoo hfsplus](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/Hfsplus)

Comment: Thanks, though I can't really see the part that actually does the compression.. maybe I'm just missing something.
As I've already mentioned, I have a DMG on hand (of sorts), as I'm able to create one with mkfs.hfsplus, but it won't show the icns file I've added under .VolumeIcon.icns because (from my understanding), the DMG needs to be compressed and made read-only for it to see that.. this last part is mainly what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround.. even though it's an ugly one.
Creating an empty DMG on Mac OS, adding the icon and everything manually, once, as a template, then just copying it to the Gentoo machine for every build, mounting, copying all the relevant files in, and dismounting.
It doesn't make it read only/compressed, but seems to be able to display the icon, which is what I needed at this point.

Comment: How do you mount it that it is writable?

Comment: It was writable when I originally created it, but I've toyed with it a bit since and now it seems they are being created write locked.. I'm guessing it has something to do with newer Mac OS versions (originally created on El Capitan).
I've just decided not to touch it anymore so that it won't stop being non writeable :)